# In Magento 2.2.5, custom login link is showing login even customers logged In

Tags: magento-2.2.5, header

In **Magento 2.2.5**, I have used the **custom phtml** file in `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml` to add the **customer header links** with following code.
But it is showing the **`login link`** even **`loggedIn`**.

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    ?>
        <li class="level0 nav-8 last level-top ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo $storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/login');?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-9" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span><?php echo __("Login")?></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php
        }else{
    ?>
    <li class="level0 nav-8 last level-top ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo $storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account');?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-9" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span><?php echo __("My Account")?></span></a>
    <ul class="logout-wrap"><li class="" role="menuitem"><a href="<?php echo $storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/logout');?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-10" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span><?php echo __("Logout")?></span></a></span></li></ul>
    </li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: which file you are using now this code?

Comment: @RakeshDonga, In  app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

we can check Customer is logged in or not by below way,
Using **Block file**, Pass `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` as a dependency to construct method.

```
<?php

namespace Rd\Customer\Block;

class Customerinfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /*
     * return bool
     */
    public function getLogin() {
        return $this->httpContext->isLoggedIn();
    }
?>
```

Call **getLogin** function in template file,

```
<?php
$isLoggedin = $block->getLogin();
        if(!$isLoggedin) {
    ?>
        <li class="level0 nav-8 last level-top ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo $storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/login');?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-9" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span><?php echo __("Login")?></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php
        }else{
    ?>
    <li class="level0 nav-8 last level-top ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo $storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account');?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-9" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span><?php echo __("My Account")?></span></a>
    <ul class="logout-wrap"><li class="" role="menuitem"><a href="<?php echo $storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/logout');?>" class="level-top ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-10" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span><?php echo __("Logout")?></span></a></span></li></ul>
    </li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: you have created block file and after run compile command ? because this code work for me

Comment: In home page alone i am getting same link. Other than that, in product detail and category pages are working.